# Why does my include appear above all of the other content?

Tags: php, oop

http://tinypic.com/r/2mn0pph/8

This happens when I do

```
<?php
  require('page.inc');

  $homepage = new Page();

  $homepage->content = include 'project.php';

 $homepage->Display();  
?>
```

But if I do this:

```
<?php
  require('page.inc');

  $homepage = new Page();

  $homepage->content = "Hello, stackoverflow!";


  $homepage->Display();  
?>
```

It does what is intend here

http://tinypic.com/r/1214vbt/8

Is there something special I should do to the include statement to get all the content between the lines?

Comment: What's in `project.php`?

Comment: both html and php to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to catch the generated HTML:

```
<?php
    require('page.inc');
    $homepage = new Page();

    ob_start();
    require 'project.php';
    $homepage->content = ob_get_clean();

    $homepage->Display();  
?>
```

This way, the PHP is executed, but there's no output to the browser. Instead you'll catch the buffered content in `$homepage->content`.

Comment: Thank you! While I don't readily understand why this worked, I will be reading the documentation about it next. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, short explaination. ;) PHP normally writes directly to the data connection with the browser. Output buffering instead catches the generated output stream and gives you the possibility to assign it to a variable. Just like in the code above.

Comment: I won't consider this a good advise. Output buffer typically is a code smell, project.php might be refactored to not output anything. Maybe $homepage->content also shouldn't be the actual content, but have some logic which dumps a files contents directly to the output ...

Comment: @johannes: I agree about the potential “code smell” of `ob_*`, but I don't want to lecture other people about architecture and software design, unless I see security issues. My general recommendation would be to use a decent framework, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

Include doesn't not return the text it outputs:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it.

---

This is what you want:

```
<?php
    require('page.inc');    
    $homepage = new Page();
    $homepage->content = file_get_contents('project.html');
    $homepage->Display();
?>
```

From the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> file_get_contents() returns the file in a string

As it was mentioned by @lxg:

"I would assume that project.php contains PHP code to be executed. In this case, file_get_contents('project.php'); would be a bad idea."

Comment: I would assume that `project.php` contains PHP code to be executed. In this case, `file_get_contents('project.php');` would be a bad idea.

Comment: Is this a bad idea because it is poor security or will the php not execute properly?

EDIT: I found out.